# QTableWidget headers not displaying

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I use the UI editor to create a QTableWidget.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    populateFilesTable();
    connect(ui->browseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(selectDirectory()));
    connect(ui->searchButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(findFiles()));
}
```

This shows how the UI is setup and then I call the function `populateFilesTable()`.

The function is as follows:

```
void MainWindow::populateFilesTable()
{
    ui->filesTable->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);

    QStringList labels;
    labels << tr("Filename") << tr("Size");
    ui->filesTable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);
    ui->filesTable->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch);
    ui->filesTable->verticalHeader()->hide();
    ui->filesTable->setShowGrid(true);
}
```

The headers aren't being displayed on the table, any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What's wrong?

The horizontal header needs the information of **columns** from `QTableWidget`. As a `QTableWidget` is instantiated, both column count and row count are null hence you got no headers show even if you called `setHorizontalHeaderLabels`.

---

### Solution

Insert columns **before** you set the header:

```
ui->filesTable->insertColumn(0);
ui->filesTable->insertColumn(1);

QStringList labels;
labels << tr("Filename") << tr("Size");
ui->filesTable->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);
```

Comment: Because of my limited knowledge of QT, I'm just trying to understand what I need to do etc. I thought there may be something missing but wasn't sure how to accomplish it. Works a treat, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

For PyQt5,

check if it is self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True) and not self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)

Idk why but after converting ui file to py file, the set this attribute as false by default.